# Ubuntu 22.04 shows systemd-journald error after I wake up from suspend

Tags: suspend, wakeup

After I wake up my computer(Mi notebook ultra 2021) from suspend it doesn't let me click the field where the password needs to be entered. I have to restart by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PRINT SCREEN</kbd> + REISUB.

Going to tty by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> shows the following 3 error in a loop at line speed :

```
Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/[computer-id]/system.journal : Input/output error

Failed to rotate /var/log/jounal/[computer-id]/user-1000.journal : Input/output error

Failed to write entry despite vacuuming, ignoring: Input/ output error
```

What can I do to fix it?

`tty` screen after waking up:

[image: tty screen after waking up]